# How do I locate Actual Amount in the table and write 0 value in the below html

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the HTML :

```
<div style="height: 383px;"><div class="v-table-row-spacer" style="height: 0px;"></div><table class="v-table-table"><tbody><tr class="v-selected v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 207px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 207px;">Наличные</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 125px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 125px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 95px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 95px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 185px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 185px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 167px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 138px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 138px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 115px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 115px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row-odd" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 207px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 207px;">Maestro OFF</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 125px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 125px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 95px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 95px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 185px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 185px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 167px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 138px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 138px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 115px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 115px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 207px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 207px;">American Express OFF</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 125px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 125px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 95px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 95px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 185px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 185px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 167px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 138px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 138px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 115px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 115px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row-odd" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 207px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 207px;">MasterCard OFF</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 125px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 125px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 95px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 95px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 185px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 185px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 167px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 138px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 138px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 115px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 115px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 207px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 207px;">Visa Card OFF</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 125px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 125px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 95px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 95px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 185px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 185px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 167px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 138px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 138px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 115px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 115px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row-odd" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 207px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 207px;">China Union Pay OFF</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 125px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 125px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 95px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 95px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 185px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 185px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 167px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 138px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 138px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 115px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 115px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 207px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 207px;">ALI PAY OFF</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 125px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 125px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 95px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 95px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 185px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 185px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 167px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 138px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 138px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 115px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 115px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row-odd" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 207px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 207px;">MIR</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 125px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 125px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 95px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 95px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 185px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 185px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 167px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 138px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 138px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 115px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 115px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 207px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 207px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 125px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 125px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 95px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 95px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 185px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 185px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 138px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 138px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 115px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 115px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row-odd" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 207px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 207px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 125px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 125px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 95px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 95px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 185px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 185px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 138px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 138px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 115px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 115px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 207px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 207px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 125px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 125px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 95px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 95px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 185px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 185px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 138px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 138px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 115px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 115px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row-odd" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 207px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 207px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 125px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 125px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 95px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 95px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 185px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 185px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 138px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 138px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 115px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 115px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 207px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 207px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 125px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 125px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 95px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 95px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 185px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 185px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 138px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 138px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 115px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 115px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row-odd" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 207px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 207px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 125px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 125px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 95px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 95px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 185px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 185px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 138px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 138px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 115px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 115px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 207px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 207px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 125px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 125px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 95px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 95px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 185px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 185px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 138px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 138px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 115px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 115px;"></div></td></tr></tbody></table><div class="v-table-row-spacer" style="height: 0px;"></div></div>
```

I am writting below code: but this doesnt seem to be working:

```
Actual_Amount=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,".//tr[@class='v-selected v-table-row v-table-focus']/td[4]"))) time.sleep(5) print("Hello, I am here ") Actual_Amount.send_keys("000") Actual_Amount.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: I am writting below code: but this doesnt seem to be working:              Actual_Amount=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,".//tr[@class='v-selected v-table-row v-table-focus']/td[4]")))
time.sleep(5)
print("Hello, I am here ")

Actual_Amount.send_keys("000")
Actual_Amount.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Comment: actual amount only accept integer values

Comment: Hello.. can anybody help here ?? Many thanks

Comment: .//tr[@Class='v-table-row v-selected']/td[4]     Have also tried with this but still could not reach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with below xpath  :

```
//div[text()='Actual Amount']/ancestor::div[@class='v-table-header-wrap']/following-sibling::div/descendant::input
```